# rake doesn't work in Rails4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I tried to rake in Ruby on Rails4, but it didn't work.
When i used Ruby which is installed at first in my mac, there was no error.
But after i installed rbenv, this error occurs.
How can I fix this problem??

```
$ bundle exec rake assets:precompile
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:220: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find rake-10.3.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:133:in `specs'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:178:in `specs_for'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:167:in `requested_specs'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `setup'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Fumiya/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/Fumiya/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

Comment: it says `Could not find rake-10.3.1 in any of the source`. Have you run `bundle install`?

Comment: I've already done...
On the Gem list, it says "Using rake (10.3.1)"

Comment: what `bundle show rake` return?

Comment: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.1

Comment: this is your problem. it should be in `~/.rbenv/...`. Review [rbenv docs](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) (pay attention on [basic-github-checkout](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#basic-github-checkout))

Comment: did you manage to fix the problem?

Comment: no.. i tried to fix it, and i reinstalled rbenv. But when i do `gem install bundler`, it says `ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.` not referring rbenv's ruby. How can i fix it?

Comment: do you have `export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"` and `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` in `bash_profile`? What is result of `type rbenv`?

Comment: No. there is only 
`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi`
on the bash_profile, and the result of `type rbenv` is
`rbenv is a function
rbenv () 
{ 
    typeset command;
    command="$1";
    if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
        shift;
    fi;
    case "$command" in 
        rehash | shell)
            eval `rbenv "sh-$command" "$@"`
        ;;
        *)
            command rbenv "$command" "$@"
        ;;
    esac
}`

Comment: maybe try to use [`rvm`](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) IMHO: it is more complicated inside but less complicated outside (for users)

Comment: Now i can!! Thank you!

Comment: It seems the answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23584884/bundler-cannot-find-rake-but-it-seems-installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

specify in your gemfile

```
gem 'rake', '10.3.1'
```

then

```
bundle install
```

and do

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: I've already done this, and rake-10.3.1 is in the gem list. But when I run rake, the error ocuures... What should i do...?