# Bundler cannot find rake but it seems installed

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I am having some struggles with bundler and rake. According to the error message, bundler can't find rake-10.3.1. Here's the thing, everything I've done seems to indicate that rake-10.3.1 is installed. I've been floating in the google-sphere for days without finding a solution that resolves this issue for me.

I'm on Mac OSX 10.8.5. Ruby version is 1.9.3-p392.

Error:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/bdr_pre_dev_spec.rb

/Users/dru.solis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `materialize': Could not find rake-10.3.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
  from /Users/dru.solis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
  from /Users/dru.solis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
  from /Users/dru.solis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:133:in `specs'
  from /Users/dru.solis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:178:in `specs_for'
  from /Users/dru.solis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:167:in `requested_specs'
  from /Users/dru.solis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
  from /Users/dru.solis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
  from /Users/dru.solis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
  from /Users/dru.solis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17
```

Here are things I've done:

- Blasted away the Gemfile.lock and tried a `bundle install`. This reinstalls gems and clearly shows rake-10.3.1 being installed but when I run rspec it still says it can't find rake.
- Manually try to install gem with `gem install rake -v 10.3.1` which also indicates that rake-10.3.1 is installed but rspec command still throws the same error.
- Explicitly specified rake 10.3.1 in the Gemfile, blasted away Gemfile.lock and `bundle install`
- Uninstall rake (all versions found) `gem uninstall rake` and reinstall rake using `gem install rake -v 10.3.1`
- Uninstalled the version of ruby I was using and reinstalled it with `rvm uninstall ruby-1.9.3-p392` and then `rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p392`.
- Downgrade bundler to 1.6.1
- Uninstall and reinstall bundler
- `rvm implode` and reinstall rvm

None of these fixed the issue.

`bundle show` says that rake-10.3.1 is installed.

```
Gems included by the bundle:
* activemodel (3.2.18)
* activesupport (3.2.18)
* amq-protocol (1.9.2)
* amqp (1.3.0)
* awesome_print (1.2.0)
* bertha-scheduler (1.1.9)
* bertha_client (0.5.5)
* builder (3.0.4)
* bundler (1.6.2)
* coderay (1.1.0)
* config_client (0.3.2)
* config_core (1.0.2)
* dao_core (2.6.3)
* diff-lcs (1.2.5)
* effin_utf8 (1.0)
* eventmachine (1.0.3)
* faraday (0.8.9)
* faraday_middleware (0.9.1)
* hashie (2.0.5)
* highline (1.6.21)
* httparty (0.11.0)
* i18n (0.6.9)
* method_source (0.8.2)
* multi_json (1.8.4)
* multi_xml (0.5.5)
* multipart-post (1.2.0)
* mysql2 (0.3.15)
* net-scp (1.2.1)
* net-sftp (2.1.2)
* net-ssh (2.9.0)
* nexus (1.2.1)
* opower-rake-tasks (0.0.2)
* outbound_client (0.0.5)
* pry (0.9.12.6)
* rabbitmq_http_api_client (1.1.0)
* rake (10.3.1)
* rspec (2.14.1)
* rspec-core (2.14.8)
* rspec-expectations (2.14.5)
* rspec-mocks (2.14.6)
* sequel (4.10.0)
* slop (3.5.0)
* term-ansicolor (1.3.0)
* thor (0.19.1)
* tins (1.1.0)
* tools_core (1.3.0)
* utility_configs (1.0.4)
```

I've checked the .rvm directory for the presence of the rake-10.3.1 gem and it's there.

```
    ls /Users/dru.solis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems
    total 0
    drwxrwxr-x  10 dru.solis  staff  340 May  9 23:22 .
    drwxrwxr-x  11 dru.solis  staff  374 May  9 23:16 ..
    drwxr-xr-x  18 dru.solis  staff  612 May  9 23:17 bundler-1.6.2
    drwxr-xr-x   8 dru.solis  staff  272 May  9 23:16 bundler-unload-1.0.2
    drwxr-xr-x  12 dru.solis  staff  408 May  9 23:16 executable-hooks-1.3.1
    drwxr-xr-x  13 dru.solis  staff  442 May  9 23:16 gem-wrappers-1.2.4
    drwxr-xr-x  16 dru.solis  staff  544 May  9 23:20 rake-10.3.1
    drwxr-xr-x   3 dru.solis  staff  102 May  9 23:16 rdoc-3.9.5
    drwxr-xr-x  13 dru.solis  staff  442 May  9 23:16 rubygems-bundler-1.4.3
    drwxr-xr-x   7 dru.solis  staff  238 May  9 23:17 rvm-1.11.3.9
```

Output of `rvm env`:

```
export PATH="/Users/dru.solis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:/Users/dru.solis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/bin:/Users/dru.solis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin:$PATH"
export GEM_HOME='/Users/dru.solis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392'
export GEM_PATH='/Users/dru.solis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392:/Users/dru.solis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global'
export MY_RUBY_HOME='/Users/dru.solis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392'
export IRBRC='/Users/dru.solis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/.irbrc'
unset MAGLEV_HOME
unset RBXOPT
```

Comment: you don't always need to `bundle exec ...` to run a command. Have you tried just doing `rspec spec/bdr_pre_dev_spec.rb`?

Comment: Same issue `rspec spec/bdr_pre_dev_spec.rb`

`BDR -PRE- Dev pipeline:`
`/Users/dru.solis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `materialize': Could not find rake-10.3.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I finally managed to get this error to go away. I started thinking it was some weird permission issue.

To solve this problem, I did the following:

- Open the Disk Utility, Applications/Utilities/Disk Utility
- Repair Permissions
- Remove the .bundle directory in my project
- Remove the vendor directory in my project
- Remove the Gemfile.lock
- `bundle install`

After that it started working without complaining about not finding rake. Crazy, man. Ugh. Hopefully this helps other folks if they run into the same issue.

Comment: Thanks. I just deleted my whole project, imported it from git and rake started to work again fine. Don't get it but... ^^